# Including strings in class

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how can i include php file in php class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578732/how-can-i-include-php-file-in-php-class)

I have a PHP file that starts like this:

```
<?php

include("strings.php");

class example {
```

The strings.php is formatted like this

```
$txt['something'] = "something";
$txt['something_else'] = "something else";
```

My question is, how do I call the `$txt['something']` inside a method in `example` class?
I know `$this->txt['something']` doesn't work

It's probably basic stuff, but I just started learning PHP

Comment: pass it into the constructor when you instantiate an object from the class or pass it into the method when calling it.

Comment: @Madzgo: What many do not use (but what you could) is the feature of `include` to actually return something. Then you would have an "anonymous" array and you can assign to any variable: `$this->txt = include('strings.php');`.

Comment: @hakre yeah, but that introduces a hidden dependency on the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

Depends:

***Do the entire (or most of the) object need the strings to work, or just a method or two?***

- If yes, you should pass it in the constructor of the object:

  ```
  class Example {
      private $texts;

      public function __construct($texts) {
          $this->texts = $texts; //Now the array is available for all of the methods in the object, via $this->texts
      }
  }

  $example = new Example($txt);
  ```
- If not, you should pass it in **to the relevant method** which needs it.

  ```
  class Example {
      private $texts;

      public function method($texts) {
          //Do stuff with $texts
      }
  }

  $example = new Example;
  $example->method($txt);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

An included file that just defines variables generally is a sign for bad design and definitely not OOP. But if you have to work with that, include the file from within the class and let it *return* the array:

```
class Example
{
    protected $txt;
    public function __construct($include = 'strings.php')
    {

        $this->txt = include($include);
    }
    public function someMethod()
    {
        return $this->txt['somestring'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Unless strings.php contains any more wrapping code $txt is a global variable.
Php does not allow access to normal global variables from within functions and methods unless explicitly declared.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

You call it by first declaring it in the function

```
class MyClass{

public function MyMethod() {
{
    global $txt;
    echo $txt['fddf'];
```

This is a citation from php.net

```
<?php
$a = 1; /* global scope */ 

function test()
{ 
    echo $a; /* reference to local scope variable */ 
} 

test();
?>

This script will not produce any output because the echo statement refers to a local version of the $a variable
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be obvious that if the variable is global, you would not need the object any longer to access it?

Comment: $txt is declared in global context but PHP does not provide access to global variables by default inside functions and methods, you have to tell the function that the variable is global as noted int the link I provided. Unless they are super globals $_NNN: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Comment: Well, obvious or not, PHP globals are NOT available within a function or method unless you explicitly tell the method that it is a global variable. If you just start using it it will be created as a local variable in the context of the function. So no Php globals do require declaration as the link to php documentation clearly states and I would really like to know why the down votes?

Comment: @DavidMårtensson: Because globals are evil. Your object needs the $txt array to work, but it does not **say** that it needs it, it doesn't appear in the constructor's contract, nor does it appear on any methods, it's just there. And if you by any chance attempted to start the object before you initiated the global variable, you'll get an unexplainable run-time error, which will drive you mad.

Comment: Well even if Globals are evil, my answer still is an answer to the question that would work in the example supplied, and if he is learning, he will probably encounter this exact solution in existing projects, so he should know about it. So I do think my answer is useful even though there might be more elegant solutions.